# Problems with specifiying TM_fill when creating a map in R with TM_maps

Tags: r, polygon, vector, mapping, sp

For my research I am visualizing plastic contents in segments of water.
After creating my segment (online, polygons in KML-file) I jointed it with my table with fieldworkdata with plastics per segment.

Creating a map with these segments works fine until I want to combine the amount of plastic and the segments. My code is the following:

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd("C:/Users/......................../Thesis") # Set working directory (change to your own location)

#packages
library("sf")
library("raster")
library("sp")
library("spData")
library("spDataLarge")
library(tmap)    # for static and interactive maps
library(leaflet) # for interactive maps
library(ggplot2) # tidyverse data visualization package
install.packages("rgdal") #importing KML files
library("rgdal")

(rgdal_show_exportToProj4_warnings="none")

library(dplyr)
library(stringr) # for working with strings (pattern matching)
library(tidyr)

#Load data for segments
Meet3 <- read.csv2("Weeklydata/DataMeet3.csv", header = TRUE)

segmenttest <- st_read("R maps/polygons/PolygonsLeiden.kml")
Meet3$Segments <- c("1","2","3","4", "5", "6","7","8","9","10", "11", "12","13","14","15","16", "17", "18","19","20","21","22", "23", "24","25","26","27","28", "29","0")
PlasticData =Meet3[c(-30),]


PolOnly <- segmenttest[ ,1,3]
PolOnly$Segments <- c("1","2","3","4", "5", "6","7","8","9","10", "11", "12","13","14","15","16", "17", "18","19","20","21","22", "23", "24","25","26","27","28", "29")

#Combine data
PlasticMap = left_join(PlasticData, PolOnly)
current.mode <- tmap_mode("view") #switch to interactive map


plot(st_geometry(PlasticMap$geometry), col = PlasticMap$total.per.segment) (this works fine!!, but i want to create TM_maps)


Map1 = tm_shape(PlasticMap$geometry) +   tm_polygons("total.per.segment")
```

The problem is that when running Map1, the following error occurs:

> Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name

Link to 2 files with example of the datafiles:
https://we.tl/t-jLvLZHlWUM

Comment: What's the problem? Does this code produce an error message or does it not do what you want it to do? And we can't run this code because we don't have your data. Can you make a simple example that shows your problem?

Comment: @Spacedman i tried to clearify my problem: is it more clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> Map1 = tm_shape(PlasticMap$geometry) +   tm_polygons("total.per.segment")
> Map1
Error: Fill argument neither colors nor valid variable name(s)
```

That doesn't work because `PlasticMap$geometry` is just the geometry column. If `tm_shape` has only got the geometry column, then it can't get the other columns. So let's send it the `PlasticMap` object completely (it will work out to use the correct geometry column):

```
> Map1 = tm_shape(PlasticMap) +   tm_polygons("total.per.segment")
> Map1
Error: Object PlasticMap is neither from class sf, stars, Spatial, nor Raster.
```

That error is because `PlasticMap` is a plain data frame and not a spatial one. In the `left_join`, you are joining onto a non-spatial data frame so all the spatial metadata from `PolOnly` has gone. You can use `st_as_sf` to make it spatial, and it will use the `geometry` column:

```
> PlasticMap = st_as_sf(PlasticMap)
```

You should probably make sure it has the same coordinate system as the spatial data it came from:

```
> PlasticMap = st_as_sf(PlasticMap, crs=st_crs(PolOnly))
```

Then you can do:

```
> Map1 = tm_shape(PlasticMap) +   tm_polygons("total.per.segment")
> print(Map1)
```

and that seems to work.